# Can you specify correlated coefficients in Stan models?

Tags: bayesian, correlation, stan, correlation-matrix

Closest question I could find to mine was [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474647/what-is-meant-by-correlation-between-intercept-and-slopes/474649#474649), which doesn't cover it.

Is it possible to specify a correlation between two parameters in a Stan model? Consider a linear regression specified by:

$$
\begin{align}
y &\sim Normal(\mu, \sigma) \\
\mu &= \alpha + \beta \times x \\
\alpha &\sim Normal(0, 1) \\
\beta &\sim Normal(0, 1) \\
\sigma &\sim Exponential(1)
\end{align}
$$

Can I add a parameter for the correlation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$? I know that in random effect models, for example, you can have a variance-covariance matrix for intercepts and slopes. Is there something analogous for fixed effects?

Comment: Why not put a prior on the joint distribution of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  That way, you can specify the correlation be whatever you want

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want. Do you have to specify any new parameters for that? Or can you specify a joint prior? I tried looking at the documentation for "Multivariate Changes of Variables" and didn't understand what it was talking about. Am I looking in the wrong place? Thanks for your help, I'm pretty new to Bayesian stats in case that's not obvious haha.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to use the `multi_norm` family of log probability density functions in the model block of your stan program.

Here is an example of putting a joint prior on the coefficients of the linear model.  As per your request, the two parameters will be correlated with a correlation of $\rho$.

```r
library(cmdstanr)
#> This is cmdstanr version 0.6.1.9000
#> - CmdStanR documentation and vignettes: mc-stan.org/cmdstanr
#> - CmdStan path: /Users/demetripananos/.cmdstan/cmdstan-2.33.1
#> - CmdStan version: 2.33.1
#> 
#> A newer version of CmdStan is available. See ?install_cmdstan() to install it.
#> To disable this check set option or environment variable CMDSTANR_NO_VER_CHECK=TRUE.
library(tidyverse)

stan_code <- '
data{
  int n;
  int p;
  vector[n] x;
  vector[n] y;
  matrix[p, p] A;
}
transformed data{
 matrix[n, 2] X;
 X[, 1] = rep_vector(1.0, n);
 X[, 2] = x;
}
parameters{
  vector[p] beta;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model{
  sigma ~ exponential(1.0);
  beta ~ multi_normal_cholesky(rep_vector(0.0, p), A);
  y ~ normal(X * beta, sigma);
}
'

n <- 10
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2*x + 1 + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)

## Construct the desired covariance matrix
## Here, prior variances are 1, and correlation between
## parameters is 0.8
variances <- diag(c(1, 1))
correlation_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1), nrow = 2)
covariance_matrix <- variances %*% correlation_matrix %*% variances
A <- chol(covariance_matrix)

stan_data = list(n=n, x=x, y=y, A=A, p=nrow(A))

model <- write_stan_file(stan_code) %>% 
         cmdstan_model()
#> /Users/demetripananos/.cmdstan/cmdstan-2.33.1/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/tbb_2020.3/build/Makefile.tbb:28: CONFIG: cfg=release arch=arm64 compiler=clang target=macos runtime=cc15.0.0_os14.4
#> ld: warning: duplicate -rpath '/Users/demetripananos/.cmdstan/cmdstan-2.33.1/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/tbb' ignored


model$sample(stan_data)
#> Running MCMC with 4 sequential chains...
#> 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  100 / 2000 [  5%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  300 / 2000 [ 15%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  500 / 2000 [ 25%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  700 / 2000 [ 35%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:  900 / 2000 [ 45%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1100 / 2000 [ 55%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1300 / 2000 [ 65%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1500 / 2000 [ 75%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1700 / 2000 [ 85%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1900 / 2000 [ 95%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 finished in 0.0 seconds.
#> Chain 2 Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  100 / 2000 [  5%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  300 / 2000 [ 15%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  500 / 2000 [ 25%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  700 / 2000 [ 35%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:  900 / 2000 [ 45%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1100 / 2000 [ 55%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1300 / 2000 [ 65%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1500 / 2000 [ 75%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1700 / 2000 [ 85%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1900 / 2000 [ 95%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 finished in 0.0 seconds.
#> Chain 3 Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  100 / 2000 [  5%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  300 / 2000 [ 15%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  500 / 2000 [ 25%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  700 / 2000 [ 35%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:  900 / 2000 [ 45%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1100 / 2000 [ 55%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1300 / 2000 [ 65%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1500 / 2000 [ 75%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1700 / 2000 [ 85%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1900 / 2000 [ 95%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 finished in 0.0 seconds.
#> Chain 4 Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  100 / 2000 [  5%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  300 / 2000 [ 15%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  500 / 2000 [ 25%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  700 / 2000 [ 35%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:  900 / 2000 [ 45%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1100 / 2000 [ 55%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1300 / 2000 [ 65%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1500 / 2000 [ 75%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1700 / 2000 [ 85%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1900 / 2000 [ 95%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 finished in 0.0 seconds.
#> 
#> All 4 chains finished successfully.
#> Mean chain execution time: 0.0 seconds.
#> Total execution time: 0.6 seconds.
#>  variable  mean median   sd  mad    q5  q95 rhat ess_bulk ess_tail
#>   lp__    -1.41  -1.01 1.50 1.24 -4.37 0.24 1.00     1503     1425
#>   beta[1]  1.01   1.00 0.12 0.11  0.83 1.20 1.00     2141     1595
#>   beta[2]  2.03   2.06 0.19 0.16  1.69 2.29 1.00     1789     1310
#>   sigma    0.35   0.33 0.13 0.10  0.21 0.58 1.00     1502     1477
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>